# Can't use Vercel /api serverless functions with /app/api from Next.js

Tags: next.js, vercel

I followed https://vercel.com/guides/how-to-use-python-and-javascript-in-the-same-application and specifically https://github.com/digitros/nextjs-fastapi/tree/main/app example and have working locally Next.js with fallback to python for some /api/ml/path* routes.

The problem is that when I deploy that on Vercel /api takes precedence and never fallbacks to /app/api so I am getting 404 in logs. How can I configure it that it goes for /api and if not then /app/api ?